# cx_freeze program not working on other machines

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a program with cx_freeze, and the .exe works on my Windows 10 machine, but when testing it on another Windows 7 machine, the process appears in the task manager but no terminal windows opens. Here is my setup.py, I am calling it using "python setup.py build"

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {
"include_msvcr": True   #skip error msvcr100.dll missing
}
exe=Executable(
     script="xboxNAO.py",
     icon="icon.ico",
     base=None
     )

includefiles=[]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(

     version = "0.0",
     description = "Nao XBOX Control",
     author = "MFC",
     name = "Naobox",
     options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

Comment: The platform programs are freezed or compiled on are generally the only platform which will allow the program to be run. Pyinstaller is a better alt to cxFreeze

Comment: I just tried using pyinstaller and the same thing happens: The process starts and continues to show in the task manager's process window, but the terminal doesn't appear.

Comment: Windows distinguishes between console and gui apps. Did you accidentally create a GUI app? (I'm not sure what setting you need to change.)

Comment: There are also some small differences between frozen apps and normal Python scripts. Have you tried the same command with a simple hello world script?